# Two ajax requests are executing Rails controller multiple times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ajax function **intentionally** running twice in close succession (w/ different params), but in Rails I'm receiving anywhere from 8-14 server calls, divided among the two sets of params.

- The number of times it's executing seems to change from request to request.
- I've confirmed with console messages that the Javascript is executing twice as required.
- The two ajax functions can occur very quickly, in as little as <1s.

#### Ajax:

```
function receiveData(args) {
  var payload = args[0];
  var context = payload.id;
  var feedback = payload.value;

  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= generate_response_url(@program.id) %>/" + feedback
  }).done(function(output) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(output);
  });
}
```

#### Routes:

```
get 'requests/generate_response/:program_id' => 'requests#generate_response', as: 'generate_response'
```

#### Requests controller:

```
before_action :require_user

def generate_response
  ...some data processing...
  render text: @message
end
```

#### Server logs:

```
# Received happens 4-7 times then Complete happens 4-7 times

Started GET "/requests/generate_response/5/42/received" for ::1 at 2015-07-28 17:09:04 -0400
Processing by RequestsController#generate_response as */*
  Parameters: {"program_id"=>"5", "request_id"=>"42", "message"=>"received"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Program Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."company_id" = $1 AND "programs"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 5]]
  Request Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."user_id" = $1 AND "requests"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 42]]
*** @message: ["received", "Program has begun processing your request."] ***
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "requests" SET "custom" = $1, "response_time" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "requests"."id" = $4  [["custom", "\"times_called\"=>\"6\""], ["response_time", "4.83"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-28 21:09:04.819523"], ["id", 42]]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
*** @message: ["received", "Program has begun processing your request."] ***
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/requests/generate_response/5/42/complete" for ::1 at 2015-07-28 17:09:06 -0400
Processing by RequestsController#generate_response as */*
  Parameters: {"program_id"=>"5", "request_id"=>"42", "message"=>"complete"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Program Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."company_id" = $1 AND "programs"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 5]]
  Request Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."user_id" = $1 AND "requests"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 42]]
*** @message: ["complete", "Your program is complete."] ***
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "requests" SET "custom" = $1, "completion_time" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "requests"."id" = $4  [["custom", "\"times_called\"=>\"11\""], ["completion_time", "6.35"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-28 21:09:06.341278"], ["id", 42]]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
*** @message: ["complete", "Your program is complete."] ***
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code on how you are calling the function receiveData

Comment: @taxicala receiveData() is being called via Autobahn, so that's an external source. However, I injected console.log messages into receiveData() and they confirmed that the function itself is being run exactly twice.

Comment: Posting the logs from your server showing the redundant accesses would be helpful, too.

Comment: @RobertNubel server logs added.